# Running curl with exec.Command failed with "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"

Tags: go, curl, command-line

Using this code

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("curl", " -F", " tarball=@"+tgzpath, " --request", " POST", " -H", fmt.Sprintf("Authorization: Bearer %s", Token )," ","http://localhost:1880/nodes")
```

but it is giving:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
...
```

The same `curl` command is working fine in terminal:

```
curl -F tarball=@/tgzpath --request POST -H "Authorization: Bearer [Token]" http://localhost:1880/nodes
```

Comment: try to use `curl` command locally first to see if you are getting correct response.... then try to run it in golang

Comment: in local it is working fine but if i try to code it is throwing curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL error

Comment: can you mention the curl command which is working... by editing your question

Comment: updated command - curl -F tarball=@/tgzpath --request POST -H "Authorization: Bearer Token" http://localhost:1880/nodes

Answer (score 1):

You should remove all the leading spaces in the arguments:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("curl", "-trace", "-F", "tarball=@"+tgzpath, "--request", "POST", "-H", fmt.Sprintf("Authorization: Bearer %s", Token), "https://httpbin.org/get/200")
```

See the difference between  `-F` and `-F` below:

```
$ curl " -F"
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
$ curl "-F"
curl: option -F: requires parameter
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```