# Why doesn't the file appear after exec.Command("iconv", ...)?

Tags: go

I am trying to convert the encoding of the file, but the resulting file does not appear. The command from the console runs correctly.

```
func main() {
    from := "WINDOWS-1251"
    filename := "3_win1251.csv"
    cmd := exec.Command("iconv", fmt.Sprintf("-f %s", from), fmt.Sprintf("-t UTF-8//TRANSLIT %s", filename), fmt.Sprintf("-o ./convert_%s", filename))
    // command: /usr/bin/iconv -f WINDOWS-1251 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT 3_win1251.csv -o ./convert_3_win1251.csv
    log.Println(cmd.String())
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(cmd.ProcessState)
}
```

result: `exit status 0` and the lack of a file.

file: [3_win1251.csv](https://dropmefiles.com/BO8cr)

os: debian 11

Comment: try `cmd := exec.Command("iconv", "-f", from, "-t", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", filename, "-o", fmt.Sprintf("./convert_%s", filename))`. See a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278028.

Comment: result your command: exit status 1

Comment: Print the stdout and stderr to see what's wrong. See an example here: https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec@go1.20.4#example-Cmd.CombinedOutput

Comment: @ZekeLu you exec command result err: `iconv: cannot open output file: No such file or directory`. My exec command stderr amd stdout is empty, result code 0.

Comment: My money is on this being a matter of the working directory.

Comment: This one worked for me: https://go.dev/play/p/7ZC9OIW_yhL. The file `3_win1251.csv` is in the same folder as the `main.go` file. And I run the app with `go run .`.

Comment: lol, go run worked for me. Run from GoLand cannot open output file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth mentioning that `strace` is a perfect tool for diagnosing such kind of problems:

```
$ strace iconv -f WINDOWS-1251 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT 3_win1251.csv -o ./convert_3_win1251.csv 2>&1 | grep -F execve
execve("/usr/bin/iconv", ["iconv", "-f", "WINDOWS-1251", "-t", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", "3_win1251.csv", "-o", "./convert_3_win1251.csv"], 0x7fffeed6e768 /* 55 vars */) = 0
```

Comparing to:

```
$ strace -f ./main 2>&1 | grep -F execve
execve("./m", ["./m"], 0x7ffd85261008 /* 55 vars */) = 0
[pid 2745776] execve("/usr/bin/iconv", ["iconv", "-f WINDOWS-1251", "-t UTF-8//TRANSLIT 3_win1251.csv", "-o ./convert_3_win1251.csv"], 0xc0001ba000 /* 55 vars */ <unfinished ...>
[pid 2745776] <... execve resumed>)     = 0
```

It's easy to spot that the arguments are different. Note that the `-f` option cause it to trace child processes.

While on Windows, we can use the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) tool. Let's borrow the command from the question [exec with double quoted argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954729/exec-with-double-quoted-argument).

When running in `cmd.exe`:

```
find "SomeText" file.txt
```

The `Command line` is `find "SomeText" file.txt` (see the screenshot below).

[image: Process Create by cmd.exe]

But when running with `exe.Command`, the `Command line` is `find \"SomeText\" file.txt` (see the screenshot below). The `"` are incorrectly escaped. And as suggested by the answer for that question, the solution is to set the whole command line directly.

[image: Process Create by cmd.Command]